# Play music on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So Basically, this is for customixing a profile layout on a website.

I do not have access to change the websites html and I know that there is no `<audio>` tag on the webpage.
But I can import external scripts like javascript, css etc.

So I wanted to ask if there is any way to modify a `<img>` or `<a>` tag to additionally play a music file on mouse over with css, jscript or another language.

Comment: Yes, with javascript, you can make many changes to an existing webpage.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript:

```
var item = document.getElementById("img");
var music = new Audio('music.mp3');

item.addEventListener("mouseover", playMusic, false);
item.addEventListener("mouseout", stopMusic, false);

function playMusic() {
   music.play();
}

function stopMusic() {
   music.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the answer above mine is not quite right, to be honest, it starts playing, but it doesn't stop because `music.stop();` doesn't exist you should use:

`music.pause();` - to pause audio
`music.currentTime = 0;` - to make audio go from start.

```js
var item = document.getElementById("img");
var music = new Audio('music.mp3');

item.addEventListener("mouseover", playMusic, false);
item.addEventListener("mouseout", stopMusic, false);

function playMusic() {
   music.play();
}

function stopMusic() {
   music.pause();
   music.currentTime = 0;
}
```

If you want to just let it continue on the next hover from where it ended use this:

```js
var item = document.getElementById("img");
var music = new Audio('music.mp3');

item.addEventListener("mouseover", playMusic, false);
item.addEventListener("mouseout", pauseMusic, false);

function playMusic() {
   music.play();
}

function pauseMusic() {
   music.pause();
}
```

Comment: You also have to be aware that most browsers don't allow playing music without a user interaction (clicking, etc)